# What is the equivalent of constructor in the createReactClass approach?

Tags: reactjs

Simple question: say that using `React.Component` I have such a code:

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
  }
}
```

What will be the equivalent of this using the `createReactClass` approach?

**Edit:**
I've read that I can use `getInitialState` for initial state, but is it a good place for creating refs?

Comment: Have you viewed the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html)?

Comment: Yes, I've read that I can use getInitialState for state, but I'm still not sure that this method works exactly like the constructor and that I can create refs also there.

Comment: And generally refs has nothing to do with getting initial state, so it would be problematic at least in terms of naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like an `initialize` method, where you have access to component instance and is called before `render`.

The closest method I can think of is:

[`unsafe_componentwillmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

> `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, **we recommend using the constructor() instead for initializing state**.

(Emphasis mine).

React docs specifically recommends using constructor instead of this life cycle hook, but if you don't have access to "constructor" itself then this is the closest thing imo.